# How to query Solr with spaces and slashes in the filters?

Tags: solr, content-search

I have a Sitecore 8.1 instance using Solr 4.10.  I have a custom field in my Solr index called read_roles. It is a list of Sitecore roles that can read a given item. Here is an example of what that looks like in the index when viewed through the Solr UI.

```
"read_roles_sm": [
          "extranet\\DistribA",
          "extranet\\Anonymous Role",
          "extranet\\Approved Role" ]
```

My first question is this: Are these values *really* stored with two slashes like that? Or is a slash a special character or something and the Solr UI is adding that in only when it is being displayed on the web page?

I have code that adds a security filter to my query that looks like this:

```c#
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySecurityFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : SearchResultItem {

    var userRoles = Sitecore.Context.User.Roles.Select(r => r.Name);

    var readPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
    readPredicate = userRoles.Aggregate(readPredicate, (current, role) => current.Or(i => i["read_roles"].Equals(role)));

    var denyPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
    denyPredicate = userRoles.Aggregate(denyPredicate, (current, role) => current.And(i => !i["denied_roles"].Equals(role)));

    if (readPredicate.Body.NodeType != System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.Constant) {
        query = query.Filter(readPredicate);
    }
    if (readPredicate.Body.NodeType != System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.Constant) {
        query = query.Filter(denyPredicate);
    }
    return query;
}
```

The idea here is give me all results where at least one of the user's roles is in the read_roles field and none of the user's roles are in the denied_roles field.

I seem to be running in to all kinds of problems with slashes and spaces and I don't really understand what is going on here and I don't know how to troubleshoot it.  I believe this code works fine as long as the user does not belong to any roles with a space in them.

Here is an example. If I am not logged in to the site (anonymous user which belongs to the extranet\Anonymous Role) and I try a search it works properly.  I get the results that I would expect.  And I see this in the Sitecore Search log file as part of the query that was sent to Solr:

```
&fq=(((-denied_roles_sm:("extranet\\Anonymous Role") AND read_roles_sm:("extranet\\Anonymous Role"))
```

However if I log in as a user that is part of the extranet\DistribA role I do not get the results I would expect and I see this in the Sitecore Search log file:

```
&fq=(((-denied_roles_sm:(extranet\DistribA) AND read_roles_sm:(extranet\DistribA))
```

What I have noticed is that if the role has a space in it then it seems to put quotes around it and also adds a second slash.  But if the role name does not have a space in it then it doesn't do that.  I feel like I am not understanding something fundamental about how Solr handles things like spaces and slashes in queries.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## About spaces and quotes

If there is no space, then `field:foo` treats `foo` as a string value. You could write `field:"foo"` but you don't have to, since the search term doesn't contain a space.

If there is a space included, then quotes are required around the value, otherwise the query won't be parsed correctly: `field:"foo bar"`

## About backslashes

Backslashes are not stored like this: `\\`. It's just the escaping syntax that is used both in Solr queries and in the JSON representation in the Solr UI.

A backslash should actually always be escaped - see this documentation section:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters

I think that in case of `extranet\DistribA`, Sitecore's query generator has a defect that does not escape it. It's probably related to the fact that there are no quotes around the search term.

## Suggested fix

I suggest that you don't store backslashes in the index so as to overcome this defect. Sanitize your role names to remove the backslash—both when storing the custom field and when querying the index.

Comment: Ok.  Then how come my code doesn't work when searching for a role that has a space in it?  Do I need to do something to the role names before I add them to the predicate?

Comment: Ok.  The strange thing is that all of this worked perfectly in Sitecore v7.5.  Now after we have upgraded to v8.1 it no longer works.  How do I make my field "not tokenized"?

Comment: @CoreyBurnett use `indexType="UNTOKENIZED"` on the field definition in your custom index configuration.

Comment: I changed the field to be untokenized but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What kind of separate question should I create? My problem is that when I query Solr with filters that have spaces or slashes in them that it doesn't seem to work properly.  I'm not really sure what my new question should be.

Comment: FWIW I think the question is fine. My answer below is based on a similar problem I had to solve with storing urls in a multi value field in solr. The tokenization was breaking the query for anything with spaces or weird characters in the url.  Maybe rephrase the title to "How to I query literal values in Solr?" but that might not come up when someone is searching for how to query spaces, which is probably the most common problem.

Comment: This is getting rather meta. I still think the question is fine, because  most people who are going to run into this problem will approach it from the perspective of a faulty query.  They read this question and the answers, and hopefully realize the problem wasn't the query but rather how they were storing the field. If this site is meant to be a knowledge repository, we want to make it as easy as possible to find the solution to a problem.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett please see my updated answer.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I don't believe that roles have IDs.  They are not Sitecore items.  The only identifier that I know of for a role is its name.

Comment: @CoreyBurnett you are right, of course. I forgot about that. Well, then i think the best approach will be to sanitize the role names and remove backslashes.

Comment: I replaced the backslashes with the pipe character both when storing and when querying and that fixed the problem!!  Thanks so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you may need is a new field type.  The _sm field is a string field in the Solr schema.xml, specifically a multivalued string field. There's no tokenizer specified, so I believe that means it uses the default tokenizer. What you want is the [KeywordTokenizerFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-KeywordTokenizer). The KeywordTokenizerFactory treats the entire value as a literal, so it includes spaces when matching. It's also case sensitive, but you can add a LowerCaseFilterFactory if that's an issue.

Try this in the schema.xml,

```xml
<fields>
    ...    
        <dynamicField name="*_sm" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <dynamicField name="*_smnt" type="string_untokenized" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    ...
</fields>
...
<types>
    ...
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="string_untokenized" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" >
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    ...
<types>
```

Then in your Sitecore Solr config you need to add this field type, like so

```xml
<fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <!-- This element must be first -->
    <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
        <typeMatch typeName="string_multi_untokenized"  type="System.String"  fieldNameFormat="{0}_smnt"  settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    </typeMatches>
    <!-- This allows you to map a field name in Sitecore to the index and store it in the appropriate way -->
    <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
        <field fieldName="read_roles"     returnType="string_multi_untokenized" />
    </fieldNames>
</fieldMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sitecore helper `Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchContext` which is calling lucene's `Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser`. It escapes special characters. Thank you @anicho for pointing it out on slack