# How to properly search Solr for any match on one stringCollection field and no matches on a second stringCollection field?

Tags: solr, content-search

I have a Sitecore v8.1 site using Solr 4.10. Here is my index setup.  First I have two custom fields defined in my index defined as follows:

```xml
    <field fieldName="read_roles" returnType="stringCollection">MyAssembly.ReadItemRoles,MyAssembly</field>
    <field fieldName="denied_roles" returnType="stringCollection">MyAssembly.DenyReadItemRoles,MyAssembly</field>
```

The code for ReadItemRoles looks like this:

```cs
public class ReadItemRoles : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        var scIndexable = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;
        var item = (Item)scIndexable;
        List<string> rolesList = new List<string>();
        using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityEnabler())
        {
            var roles = RolesInRolesManager.GetAllRoles();
            var readRoles = roles.Where(r => item.Security.CanRead(r));
            if (readRoles != null && readRoles.Any())
            {
                rolesList = readRoles.Select(r => r.Name.Replace(@"\", "|")).ToList();
            }
        }
        return rolesList;
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```

The code for DenyReadItemRoles is similar and looks like this:

```cs
public class DenyReadItemRoles : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        var scIndexable = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;
        var item = (Item)scIndexable;
        List<string> rolesList = new List<string>();
        using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityEnabler())
        {
            var roles = RolesInRolesManager.GetAllRoles();
            var denyRoles = roles.Where(r => r.IsDenied(item));
            if (denyRoles != null && denyRoles.Any())
            {
                rolesList = denyRoles.Select(r => r.Name.Replace(@"\", "|")).ToList();
            }
        }
        if (rolesList.Count == 0)
        {
            var denyRoles = new List<string>();
            denyRoles.Add("none");
            return denyRoles;
        }
        return rolesList;
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}

internal static class SecurityExtensions
{
    internal static bool IsDenied(this Role role, Item item)
    {
        if (item.Security.CanRead(role)) return false;
        AccessRuleCollection accessRules = item.Security.GetAccessRules();
        if (accessRules != null)
        {
            foreach (AccessRule rule in accessRules)
            {
                if (rule.SecurityPermission == SecurityPermission.DenyAccess &&
                    rule.AccessRight == AccessRight.ItemRead && rule.Account == role)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return (item.Parent == null) ? false : role.IsDenied(item.Parent);
    }
}
```

So the intent here is that after I index my web database I should have a field for every item called read_roles that has a list of all of the roles that can read that item (with a | character instead of any backslashes).  And I should have a field called denied_roles that has a list of all of the roles that can't read that item.  These lists of roles are stored in a field of type stringCollection in Solr.

Now I want to apply a security filter to every site search that we do. Basically I want to show all results where at least one of the current user's roles is in the read_roles field and none of the user's roles are in the denied_roles field.  Here is my code to do that:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySecurityFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : SearchResultItem {

    var userRoles = Sitecore.Context.User.Roles.Select(r => r.Name.Replace(@"\", "|"));

    var readPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
    readPredicate = userRoles.Aggregate(readPredicate, (current, role) => current.Or(i => i["read_roles"].Equals(role)));

    var denyPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
    denyPredicate = userRoles.Aggregate(denyPredicate, (current, role) => current.And(i => !i["denied_roles"].Equals(role)));

    if (readPredicate.Body.NodeType != System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.Constant) {
        query = query.Filter(readPredicate);
    }
    if (readPredicate.Body.NodeType != System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.Constant) {
        query = query.Filter(denyPredicate);
    }
    return query;
}
```

The logic here is that I am getting a list of all of the current user's roles and I am extracting out a list of all of the role names and I am replacing any backslashes with the | character.  Then I am using the OR operator to compare each role name to see if any of them are in the read_roles field.  And I am using the AND operator to make sure none of them are in the denied_roles field.

For some reason this isn't working and I am having a lot of trouble figuring out why it is failing. The best that I can figure out is that this code seems to be failing when the user belongs to a role that contains a space in it. And only the denied_roles part of the query is failing. I have been troubleshooting this by opening up the Sitecore Search.config file and looking at the query that was sent to Solr. If I manually issue the same query to Solr using the Solr UI I get zero results.  Then if I remove the denied_roles part I get results.  So I am thinking it has something to do with the denied_roles field. But I am really not 100% sure.

EDIT:
Here is an example of a query that doesn't seem to be working.  I got this from the Sitecore Search.log file.

```cs
?q=(-isstandardvalue_b:(True) AND _language:(en)) AND (_content:(*acrygen*) OR _name:(*acrygen*) OR (short_description_t:(*acrygen*))^5 OR (search_title_t:(*acrygen*))^5)&start=0&rows=10&fl=*,score
&fq=((((-denied_roles_sm:("extranet|Anonymous Role") AND -denied_roles_sm:("extranet|Approved Role")) AND (read_roles_sm:("extranet|Anonymous Role") OR read_roles_sm:("extranet|Approved Role"))) AND _latestversion:(1)))
```

Comment: Has any of my two suggestions helped you?

Answer (score 5):

### Tokenization

I think that this problem is caused by the fact that your role fields are currently tokenized. I know that making the fields `UNTOKENIZED` in [**your previous question**](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/) didn't help, but please try once again with the following instructions.

First, locate you computed fields under `<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">` and make sure they are untokenized. For example:

```xml
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
  <field fieldName="read_roles" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" returnType="stringCollection">MyAssembly.ReadItemRoles,MyAssembly</field>
  <field fieldName="denied_roles" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" returnType="stringCollection">MyAssembly.DenyReadItemRoles,MyAssembly</field>
</fields>
```

Then **also** add these fields to the `<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">` section (which is located under the `<fieldMap>` node):

```xml
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
  <field fieldName="read_roles" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" returnType="stringCollection" />
  <field fieldName="denied_roles" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" returnType="stringCollection" />
</fieldNames>
```

Rebuild your index and see if the queries work well now.

### Sanitization

If the above doesn't help, then try replacing all non-alphanumeric characters with underscores and converting role names to lower case. This is sort of a hack, but at least it will make sure that there are no problems with tokenization and casing.

Put this method into a helper class and use it both in your computed fields and in the search query:

```cs
private static Regex _regex = new Regex("[^a-z0-9]+");

public static string SanitizeRoleName(string roleName)
{
  return _regex.Replace(roleName.ToLower(), "_");
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmytro, index rebuild is required if you add indexType="untokenized"   ?

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde yes